# Split the String by colon and display in new line from xml

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have a String like this in xml tag:

```
He is what do you need to study: <Enter>
(i) Study chapter by chapter.
(ii) Work out the revision question.
```

But its displaying like this

```
He is what do you need to study:(i) Study chapter by chapter.(ii) Work out the revision question.
```

So how can i display like how it is in xml.

Comment: Replace the "<" with &lt; and the ">" with &gt;

Comment: He means indented like XML

Comment: use line break in output. try to format it using \n and \t. Moreover if you are using xml file, read it using some xml library instead of simple file io operations. what you gave above is simple text documents. XML has tags in it to define the value. Be more specific with your question.

Comment: Is this inside your strings.xml resource file or is it xml data you are getting from elsewhere?

Comment: from xml data not strings file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using HTML:

```
Here is what do you need to study:
    <ul type="upper-roman">
       <li>Study chapter by chapter.</li>
       <li>Work out the revision question.</li>

    </ul>
```

You mean like this?

```
<div>
    Here is what do you need to study:
    <ul type="upper-roman">
       <li style="padding-left:20pt" >Study chapter by chapter.</li>
       <li style="padding-left:20pt" >Work out the revision question.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i am able to get the entire string now how can i split it after colon: and display the 2 in next lines?

Comment: No i am displaying the data dynamically so i need to check first if it contains (i) and (ii) or something like that , so if it contains then add <br> tag and display,

Comment: ahh.. what language? javascript?

Comment: JAVA buddy? can you please help me on that

Comment: Don't know how to help you. Do you need a java class, method, what can you use?

Comment: i need a java code just to check if the string contains : (colon) and then if it contains then get the upper-roman and display in 2 different lines

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
<![CDATA[
He is what do you need to study: <Enter>
(i) Study chapter by chapter.
(ii) Work out the revision question.
]]>
</a>
```